# Why is this button crashing my app when I tap it? UIButtion iPhone (ARC)

Tags: iphone

Whenever I tap "newButton" my app crashes. I am using automatic reference counting.

Edit: Just tried this in a different app and it works but does not work in my own.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *fullView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 480)];
    fullView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [[self view] addSubview:fullView];

    UIImage* blackButton =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"UIButtonBlack.png"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

    // Create button
    UIButton *newButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30)];

    // Set button content alignment
    newButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    newButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    // Set button title
    [newButton setTitle:@"Do Something" forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];
    // Set button title color
    [newButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0 green:255.0f/255.0 blue:255.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];
    // Add the background image
    [newButton setBackgroundImage:blackButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Add Events
    [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showScanner:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // in case the parent view draws with a custom color or gradient, use a transparent color
    [newButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  
    // Set titleShadowColor this way (apparently, titleLabel.shadowcolor does not work)
    [newButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0 green:0.0f/255.0 blue:0.0f/255.0 alpha:.75] forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];

    // Set button titleLabel properties  
    newButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Bold" size:13.0];
    newButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);    

    [fullView addSubview:newButton];
}

- (void)showScanner:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Do something…");
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're probably not keeping a reference to your view controller. Where do you load the view controller and display the view?

Comment: I load the view from the rootviewcontroller when a button is tapped and this is the code I use to display it     RewardsViewController *rewardsView = [[RewardsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.view insertSubview:rewardsView.view aboveSubview:tabBar];

Comment: Crash log and stack trace, please provide them.

Comment: Just added. Hopefully that is what your looking for.

Comment: A stack trace in Human-readable language would be best. just send a screen grab of what Xcode shows you. You are running in debug mode right?

Comment: Hopefully that is better. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: I've tried the code in a single view and it works fine but once I tried to add it as a subview it crashes.

Comment: Do you know at exactly which line it crashes? Try setting some breakpoints and see where it crashes. That will give you some more indication on what to do.

Comment: @joerick is right. If he writes that as an answer, you should accept it. You're creating a view controller, taking its view to put in a different hierarchy, and then letting the view controller itself go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not keeping a reference to your view controller. You either need to

- use a standard iOS view controller manager like UITabBarController or UINavigationController to display your views
- keep a reference (in an instance variable) to this view controller within the class that you opened it from.

Note that if you were to re-write this code with ARC turned off, you'd have a memory leak, instead of a crash.

The problem is that all references to the view controller from the view are *weak* references, meaning that they don't retain the controller*. So in your loading code ARC releases the view controller after you've made it and accessed its view, and it's gone.

Within your app you should keep track of all the view controllers, and access their views through them. Something like UINavigationController does this for you.

*This is because the view controller is considered to have ownership over the view, and if the view controller retained the view and the view retained the view controller, there'd be a retain loop, and neither of them would ever be released.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `UIControlState`'s cannot be `&` (or `|`) together because according to the [`UIControl` Reference Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> a control can have more than one state at a time.

Try separating them out like this:

```
// Set button title
[newButton setTitle:@"Do Something" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newButton setTitle:@"Do Something" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[newButton setTitle:@"Do Something" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

// Set button title color
[newButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0 green:255.0f/255.0 blue:255.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0 green:255.0f/255.0 blue:255.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[newButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0 green:255.0f/255.0 blue:255.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

// Add the background image
[newButton setBackgroundImage:blackButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Add Events
[newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showScanner:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// in case the parent view draws with a custom color or gradient, use a transparent color
[newButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  

// Set titleShadowColor this way (apparently, titleLabel.shadowcolor does not work)
[newButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0 green:0.0f/255.0 blue:0.0f/255.0 alpha:.75] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0 green:0.0f/255.0 blue:0.0f/255.0 alpha:.75] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[newButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0 green:0.0f/255.0 blue:0.0f/255.0 alpha:.75] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

// Set button titleLabel properties  
newButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Bold" size:13.0];
newButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
```

---

<s>It may be crashing because `button` should be `newButton`.</s>

Change this:

```
[button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0 green:0.0f/255.0 blue:0.0f/255.0 alpha:.75] forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];
```

To this:

```
[newButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0 green:0.0f/255.0 blue:0.0f/255.0 alpha:.75] forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Sorry, changed the name when I inputted it. It is that in code. Thank you for spotting that out.

Comment: I still get the same error. I started using & with UIButton because I found Apple using it with the BubbleLevel application in the developer sample code.

Comment: @morcutt Ah.  Well then, if its in Apple code it must be fine.  I can't see anything else wrong with this code, so I'm out of ideas.  Wish I could be of more help =/.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, it's been driving me nuts too. I just started rewriting this app. Prototype was without ARC and now I'm using ARC and seem to be having all sorts of issues.